# How to search through pdf media files?

Tags: search

I have a blog with reasonable number of pdf files. How can I make wordpress look into pdf files when I search it?

Thanks

Comment: You probably can't. Wordpress is made to manage content, not documents.

Comment: Well you *could*, you would just have to create a plugin that uses some other tool to do it.

Comment: I didn't expect this kind of advice to be honest :)

Comment: I experienced the same problem a few months ago, I came to know about its solutions in form of plugin which is "Full text Search". It supports PDF's Docx and many other formats. I think its link is "https://fulltextsearch.org/".

Answer (score 1):

The built in WordPress search doesn't index PDF file contents, however Google does, there's a good tutorial on DevPress on [replacing WordPress search with Google Custom Search](http://devpress.com/blog/using-google-search-within-a-wordpress-site/).

Comment: I didn't know Google would index your pdfs too. That's risky if you have some confidential pdfs.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the open-source utility, [xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/home.html), to convert the pdf file into a plan text file and search through it like any other text file. Incorporating into WordPress is another thing to worry about though.

I used it on my Mac to extract data from my company's quarterly financial statements. You could install under Mac OS X, if you've got [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/install.php) installed.

```
port install xpdf
```

You would then need to use the utility `xpdf-pdftotext` to convert the pdf file to a plain text file.

You could simply store the result in PHP as a variable

```
$file_name = '/usr/local/src/file1.pdf';

// On Mac the utility is called xpdf-pdftotext, and pdftotext on Linux I believe

if (file_exists($file_name)) {
    $file_contents = shell_exec("/opt/local/bin/xpdf-pdftotext $filename - 2>&1");

    echo $file_contents;
}
```

If you'd like to install `xpdf` from source, its available on their [website](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html), which offers both Linux and Windows versions.

Check out the [xpdf man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xpdf) to get an idea of the utility, they've got different tools for different applications. Here's the man page for the `pdftotext` utility.

Best of luck.